# Is $\langle S \rangle \cup \langle T \rangle = \langle S \cup T \rangle$ and $\langle S \rangle \cap \langle T \rangle = \langle S \cap T \rangle$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ a group, $S,T \subseteq G$ and $\langle S \rangle, \langle T \rangle$ the subgroups generated by $S$ and $T$. Is it true or false that
$$\langle S \rangle \cup \langle T \rangle = \langle S \cup T \rangle$$
and 
$$\langle S \rangle \cap \langle T \rangle = \langle S \cap T \rangle?$$

Comment: Any thoughts? Any guesses?

Comment: This can be shown false by very small counterexamples. Try $S_3$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom No

Comment: UNION DOSEN'T PLAY WELL WITH GROUPS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S=(12)$ and let $T = (13)$. Then $\langle (12)\rangle \cup\langle (13)\rangle$ has three elements (And is not even a group!).

But, $\langle (12), (13)\rangle = S_3$. This has 6  elements and IS a group.

You can do something quite similar for the intersection. The elements $S$ and $T$ should actually work as a counter example..

Explicitly: $\{(12)\}\cap\{(13)\} = \emptyset$ as a set intersection. But the intersection of $\langle (12)\rangle$ and $\langle (13)\rangle$ contains the identity.

Comment: But @Omnomnomnom said the second is true

Comment: And he/she is wrong. Hence the deleted answer!

Comment: Bu the union is true right? Could you please write down a proof? Thank you in advance:)

Comment: The statement on the union of two groups is also false. I have shown a counter example in my answer.

Comment: And $\langle \langle S \rangle \cup \langle T \rangle \rangle  = \langle S \cup T \rangle$?